# Cannot animate view with CATiledLayer correctly

Tags: iphone, uiview, ipad, catiledlayer

Can UIViews with a CATiledLayer have animations?

If I call the following:

```
[myContentView setNeedsDisplay];
```

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:context];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:10]; 
    [UIView commitAnimations];

This will work well if the UIView is a "normal" UIView without a CATiledLayer. However as soon as I add a sublayer of type CATiledLayer, the animations does not work correctly.
The page flip works, but the underlying page is not shown (just blank) until the animation is finished.

I have tried    [myContentView setNeedsDisplay]; before, after and even in the middle of the animation block. No difference if myContentView has a CATiledLayer.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

cache:YES];

Set to NO